# Application Insights alert for no log is written

Tags: azure, alert, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor

I try to create a azure alert rule which should be triggered in case my service do not log anything.

I created a query to check if my service logs something. This works fine until there are no logs in the specified time (e.g. give the provided query a filter criteria for the timestamp).

Query: `customEvents | where name == 'ShouldBeLoged' | limit 1`
This query will just give me the query result:  No results found from the last 24 hours.

If create a alert of this query the alert view shows me this (see picture): [image] [image]

Has someone an idea how I could achieve that the alert is triggered in case the service do not log anything?

Comment: Can you use | summarize count() and then compare the number with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Follow the workaround to trigger the alert if the threshold value less than 1(Means no log written):

Here I am fetching the one Limit value of custom event.
[image]

#### Workaround follows

Create alert with threshold if it less than 1 mean it will fire the alert
Here the query we used to fetch the single custom event.
[image]

We fetch single custom event, so we check the threshold value is less than 2 (it will fire if the event values is less than 2).
[image]

#### Result

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response . I also figured you the same solution but i missed to answer. My mistake was the operator and condition in the alert.