# How to create Azure metric alert that fires on null values/signal loss?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have created an Azure alert for a custom heartbeat metric - the heartbeat logs every minute, and if there are less than some count of heartbeats in a period it's supposed to fire.

However, I have found that in reality, when the service dies and stops creating heartbeats, the resulting count in the alert rules is "NULL". I can see a brief window of time where an alert condition is created while the service is dying and creating a few heartbeats, but once it's totally dead Azure is counting is as null.

I found [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained) that seems to explain the reasoning and some of the behind the scenes logic.

But it still doesn't resolve my issue - how do I create an alert based on a metric if the metric falls down to zero? In NewRelic there were "signal loss" type alerts I could create - is there something similar for Azure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-aggregation-explained#null-and-zero-values) if the service is not alive it doesn't provide the information what we expect it will add the **NULL** value in a metric database.

Make sure the Resource provider can handle the NULL while viewing the data.

> Custom metrics always use NULLs when no data is received. With [platform metrics, each resource provider decides whether to use zeros or NULLs based on what makes the most sense for a given metric.

Refer one of my [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73047004/application-insights-alert-for-no-log-is-written) for handling custom metrics alert.